# Loop through database record to generate table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I want to construct an html table based on the returned results from the database. Assuming I have a table called constraints in my database and a column called riskName and it has these values: Security, Financial, Legal and Technical as shown in the image below. How do i loop through my database and come up with this table. I have tried different approach but no has worked. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$optioner = 12;
$getObs = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM constraints WHERE constraintsID = ?");
$riski->bindParam(1, $optioner);
$riski->execute();
$result = $riski->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($getObs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr><td>".($result['riskName'])."<td><tr>";
//...other code
}
?>
</tbody>
<?php };
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to be a form as well? Also, I don't quite get the structure of your table - Where are the values for `Equal` and `How much more?` coming from?

Comment: So the four columns `Security, Financial, Legal and Technical` I assume have a value of something like 1-9. I'm just not quite getting what `importance` is, or what `Equal` is.

Comment: oh, the table headers should be: i, importance and How much more?. please ignore the Equal column. so there should be 3 columns un total. under the importance column should be the comparison (security or Financial) and under the How much (options 1-9). thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking to fix your code considered offtopic here.

Comment: Ok. i would include more code. i just wanted to get the logics of how it would work

Comment: Lastly, is there a reason that the rows go `Security or Financial` and then `Financial or Legal` rather than just the one value like `Security` 1 2 3 4 5 -- `Financial` 1 2 3 4

Comment: Yes. because I want to compare each "Risk" in the database with the next in order to construct some kind of voting.

Comment: So how are you storing that in the database? Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not seeing how you're able to get these values out of the database with out having a shit load of fields. If you only have 4 fields then you can only have 4 values, which in turn means you can only update 4 values. I will try and help the best I can, though.

Comment: Oh. all these values i.e. security, financial, etc are all under one field called risk. and when each was inserted into the db they all have a unique PK called RiskID. I also have other fields in the table but they are not needed for constructing the html table. Thanks for the help @RossWilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will give you the exact table you're looking for, but it should at least put you on the right lines. Also, you weren't keeping your variables the same and notice how `$result` is set in the while loop

```
$optioner = 12;
$riski = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM constraints WHERE constraintsID = ?");
$riski->bindParam(1, $optioner);
$riski->execute();
?>

<form>
<table>
<tr> <th>i</th> <th>Importance</th> <th>How Much More?</th> <tr>

<?php
while($result = $riski->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $result['riskName']).'<td>';
    echo '<td>';
    for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
      //radio buttons go here 
    } 
    echo'<tr>';
    //...other code
}
?>
```

Sorry I couldn't help more.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: If you downvote an answer, please say what you think/know is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ross! I will try this out now. btw.. it wasnt me who downvoted!

Comment: @saint Cheers. If you have any further questions, I'll try my best to help. :)